# Internal working of ceiling and floor function of TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, treeset

I am working on a problem where I need to find the pair in which the difference of value is at most k. Now tree set in java does that for me but I am curious to know how this is working. I am assuming it creates some sort of bucket and map that bucket with some values in a hashmap.

I checked the definition in intelliJ but couldn't find anything which explains how it works.

I found this code in Treemap and now i want to understand how it is actually working

```
final Entry<K,V> getCeilingEntry(K key) {
        Entry<K,V> p = root;
        while (p != null) {
            int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                if (p.left != null)
                    p = p.left;
                else
                    return p;
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                if (p.right != null) {
                    p = p.right;
                } else {
                    Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                    Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                    while (parent != null && ch == parent.right) {
                        ch = parent;
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                    return parent;
                }
            } else
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. It uses a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). Clue's in the name... (note that this means most operations are `O(n lg n)` rather than `O(1)` as with a hash table)

Comment: You're not going to get an answer to your second question - it's far too broad. Java is open source - what stops you from reading the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Set` data structures in Java are backed by `Map`s. The set stores elements as keys in the map and uses static object as a placeholder for values. Hence, the ceiling and floor functions are also delegated to the map. For example;

```
public E ceiling(E e) {
   return m.ceilingKey(e);
}
```

So the `TreeSet` is backed by a `TreeMap`.

The `TreeMap` is a red-black tree (at least in Java 7 and onwards) which is a self-balancing binary search tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to understand how this function is working internally

Comment: Java is open source, why don't you go to the `TreeMap` class and see? For example; `getCeilingEntry`. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am doing that only but I want to understand the actual working behind this code.